# Trouble between "for ..." and "for the ..."

Tags: articles, for

I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere.

In writing an article title, I proposed "A new material for the manufacture of bricks". A colleague of mine believes this should be "A new material for manufacture of bricks".

This sounds strange to my foreign ear, but I don't have a rigorous reason.

Is there a rule in this case? Are both valid with different connotations?

Answer (score 6):

Here's [the relevant usage chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=material%20for%20the%20manufacture%20of%2Cmaterial%20for%20manufacture%20of%2Cmaterial%20for%20manufacturing&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

...where as you can see, the article-less form with *for **manufacture** [of X]* is far less common than either the straight noun *for **the manufacture** [of X]* OR the "gerund noun" *for **manufacturing X***. Note that the gerund version *never* includes an article.

In don't think the article-less version is actually syntactically invalid, but I would strongly advise learners to avoid it, and stick with one of the other two forms above. I can't see any *semantic* difference between any of them - it's just a stylistic choice.

Comment: Thank you very much for the data and answer. Could you expand a little on the stylistic implications?

Comment: I don't know of any stylistic implications worth posting here. The first version you wrote in your question *(A new material for the manufacture of bricks)* is by far the most common one. Stick with that for your own text, and accept that occasionally you'll read / hear other versions from other people. Just don't be too easily tempted to copy those "less common" others - it's unlikely that would ever "improve" your use of English.

Comment: 'Style choice' is polysemous between 'according to the preferences of the author' (purely subjective) ... 'conveying a certain attitude, atmosphere, 'feel', ambience, register ... to the typical reader' (involving connotation). I'd say the anarthrous choice here is more staccato, technical-sounding.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Like newspaper headline writers, technical writers have a tendency to discard "unnecessary" articles. So your assessment may be relatively accurate (insofar as that means anything for *such* a "less-favoured" choice), but I suggest it wouldn't be a good idea for learners here to assume *technical-sounding = more formal = **better** (for impressing the boss at work, say).* I doubt there are *any* contexts where the article-less version is the best choice, but I'm sure there will be contexts (especially with nouns other than ***manufacture***) where the gerund is better.